# Referencing Fragments inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with referencing my Fragments inside a ViewPager. I would like to do it because from my activity I'd like to refresh a fragment at a specified position (e.g. currently displayed fragment).

Currently I have something like this:

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "MyPagerAdapter";
    private static HashMap<Integer, EventListFragment> mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap<Integer, EventListFragment>();

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItem: "+position);
        int dateOffset = position-1;
        EventListFragment mFragment = EventListFragment.newInstance(dateOffset);
        mPageReferenceMap.put(position, mFragment);
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Log.i(TAG, "destroyItem: "+position);
        mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }


    public EventListFragment getFragment(int key) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Size of pager references: "+mPageReferenceMap.size());
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `destroyItem()` gets called more often than `getItem()`, so I'm left with null references. If I don't use `destroyItem()` to clear references to destroyed fragments... well I reference fragments that don't exist.

Is there any nice way to reference fragments that are created with `EventListFragment mFragment = EventListFragment.newInstance(dateOffset);`? Or what should I do to refresh a fragment inside a ViewPager from my activity (from options menu to be precise)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve it. The trick was to make a reference list inside Activity, not PagerAdapter. It goes like this:

```
List<WeakReference<EventListFragment>> fragList = new ArrayList<WeakReference<EventListFragment>>();

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onAttachFragment: "+fragment);
    if(fragment.getClass()==EventListFragment.class){
        fragList.add(new WeakReference<EventListFragment>((EventListFragment)fragment));
    }
}
public EventListFragment getFragmentByPosition(int position) {

    EventListFragment ret = null;
    for(WeakReference<EventListFragment> ref : fragList) {
        EventListFragment f = ref.get();
        if(f != null) {
            if(f.getPosition()==position){
                ret = f;
            }
        } else { //delete from list
            fragList.remove(f);
        }
    }
    return ret;

}
```

Of course your fragment has to implement a `getPosition()` function, but I needed something like this anyway, so it wasn't a problem.

Thanks Alex Lockwood for your suggestion with `WeakReference`!

Comment: I just finished my finals and decided to come back and see if you got things working... glad I was able to help (even if it wasn't with the main problem :P).

Comment: Question: shouldn't the fragList.remove() call be passed the weak reference, rather than the fragment?

Comment: @Michael: I started using an approach like this, and it works pretty well.  But since the fragList contains weak references, it seems the entries are subject to garbage collection, even though you still may need them.  I've seen the getFragmentByPosition() method sometimes return null, so I think that's what is happening.  Any ideas how to get around that?  Thanks.

Comment: @gcl1 I just needed to update fragments which were in the memory. If a fragment was garbage collected, than before it was visible to the user it was created again so was updated anyway. So the fragment being null wasn't a problem for me. Why do you need to update fragment which is garbage collected?

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. Add the following line in your Activity's `onCreate` method (or wherever you initialize your ViewPager):

   ```
   mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUM_ITEMS-1);
   ```

   This will keep the additional off-screen pages in memory (i.e. preventing them from being destroyed), even when they aren't currently being shown on the screen.
2. You might consider implementing your `HashMap` so that it holds `WeakReference<Fragment>`s instead of the `Fragment`s themselves. Note that this would require you to change your `getFragment` method as follows:

   ```
   WeakReference<Fragment> weakRef = mPageReferenceMap.get(position);
   return (weakRef != null) ? weakRef.get() : null;
   ```

   This has nothing to do with your problem... it's just something I noticed and thought I would bring to your attention. Keeping `WeakReferences` to your `Fragment`s will allow you to leverage the garbage collector's ability to determine reachability for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: As for the 2. => it won't solve my problem but is probably a good idea to prevent leaks, thanks. And 1. => I'll have 7 pages, maybe more in the future, is it ok to keep them all in the memory at the same time?

Comment: Hmm... well obviously the less `Fragment`s you are keeping in memory the better. If you want to access your `Fragment`s on demand from within your `Activity` (without actually switching to the `Fragment`s page) w/o keeping them all in memory, the fix would be a trickier. It might require digging into the `ViewPager` source code and seeing how it handles the `Fragment` lifecycle. I'm not aware of any way to do this, but I'll look into it when I have more time.

Comment: May I humbly suggest, if there's anything you need to get from a Fragment while it's offscreen, maybe you shouldn't be giving it to a Fragment.  Consider putting it into a Service or ContentProvider, and let your Fragment be a client to it.

Comment: I don't have access to my pc right now, but I'll also look into it tommorow. Thanks for your help:-) Just a thought - maybe there is possibility to send refresh request containing the specific position to ALL the fragments in the viewpager and the one which should update would find out that this request is directed at it?

Comment: It's definitely "possible", but like I said before, it seems like it would be complicated to implement. Sparky's suggestion seems like the way to go in this case, as it avoids the complications you might encounter with the off-screen `Fragment`s' lifecycle. Instead of requesting the `Fragment` be recreated (or forcing the `Fragment` to stay in memory, as my post originally suggested), Sparky is suggesting that you provide a more external means of accessing the `Fragment`'s state.

Comment: But it's not the case. I would like to give user possibility to refresh currently displayed fragment (data downloaded with AsyncTaskLoader) from menu (or actionbar which is essentialy the same thing) . And menu is inflated in activity... So from activity containing viewpager I have to get access to the viewpagers fragments. Doesn't sound complicated at first...

Comment: Yes, so that gives me more reason to believe that Sparky's answer is the way to go. It sounds like you want to have your AsyncTask download the data and then immediately save that data to a ContentProvider (or some other type of external database). Then you can load this data in your fragment's `onResume` method (i.e. when you switch pages, if the screen turns off, etc.). This is both in accordance with Android standards (i.e. save/load persistent state in `onPause` and `onResume`) and it doesnt require you to interfere with the ViewPager/Fragment lifecycle.

Comment: I read about Content Providers and it seems like an overkill. I don't use typical AsyncTasks, I have 5-6 different AsyncTaskLoaders in my app, everything works very well, no leaks, data is reused automatically, saved in sqlite etc. Changing any of these loaders to use Conent Provider just to have possibility to redownload the data for one fragment really doesn't seem like a solution. And as far as the documentation goes, I don't really have reasons to use it.